# Align div in one line, extreme left, middle , extreme right

Tags: jquery, html, css

I have mainly 3 divs under the parent class wrapped_inside. I want to align all 3 divs in a single row. One at the middle rest of the two divs at extreme left and right ends. Below code works fine in all browser except IE.

Please note that the below css and html page is part of a larger html. I have copied only the important parts for the demo example attached below.

```css
.wrapped_inside div:nth-child(3) {
  position: relative;
  display: block;
}
.wrapped_inside div:nth-child(3) div:nth-child(1) {
  float: left;
  padding-top: 5px;
}
.wrapped_inside div:nth-child(3) div:nth-child(2) {
 padding: 10px;
  position: absolute;
  left: 50%;
}
.wrapped_inside div:nth-child(3) div:nth-child(3) {
  // left: 0%;
  float: right;
  padding-top: 5px;
}
```

```html
<div class="wrapped_inside">
  <div class="arw"></div>
  <div class="arw"></div>
  <div class="arw">
    <div class="type-4">
      <div  id="one">footer text1</div>
    </div>
    <div class="type-2">
      <div class="two">
        <a href="javascript:void(0)">
          <span >text2
        </span>
        </a>
      </div>
    </div>
   <div class="type-6">
      <div >
            <a href="#">
              <span class="menu-left">0</span>
            </a>
        
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: you want footer text in left an 0 in middle annd text2 in right?

Comment: corrected the code it was a miss from my side --class should come like this [type-4]   [type-2]    [type-6]  and it should work in all browsers

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Remove this div `<div class="col-sm-6"></div>`

```css
.wrapped_inside div:nth-child(3) {
  position: relative;
  display: block;
}
.wrapped_inside div:nth-child(3) div:nth-child(1) {
  float: left;
  padding-top: 5px;
}
.wrapped_inside div:nth-child(3) div:nth-child(2) {
 padding: 10px;
  position: absolute;
  left: 50%;
}
.wrapped_inside div:nth-child(3) div:nth-child(3) {
  // left: 0%;
  float: right;
  padding-top: 5px;
}
```

```html
<div class="wrapped_inside">
  <div class="arw"></div>
  <div class="arw"></div>
  <div class="arw">
    <div class="type-4">
      <div  id="one">footer text1</div>
    </div>
    <div class="type-2">
      <div class="two">
        <a href="javascript:void(0)">
          <span >text2
        </span>
        </a>
      </div>
    </div>        
    <div class="type-6">
      <div >
            <a href="#">
              <span class="menu-left">0</span>
            </a>
        
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: corrected the code it was a miss from my side --class should come like this [type-4]   [type-2]    [type-6]  and it should work in all browsers

Comment: Glad to help you :)